# Why do I want to keep apparmor on my system?

Tags: linux, security, app-armor

I'm running a Linux desktop behind a firewall. I've been doing that for years without using apparmor; but recently I upgraded my distro and it got installed. I see its log line, and am wondering - why am I wasting clock cycles on this thing? ... But that's not my question. In order to make the call, I would like to understand:

How is apparmor helping me, a desktop user who's not running some exposed server, in a significant way (which might merit the extra overhead on my I/O)?

Notes:

- In case it matters - I'm using Devuan 3 Beowulf (~= Debian 10 Buster).
- No need to opine on whether apparmor is useful enough or not - just explain its main aspects of utility.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question will always be down to your individual use case. If you are confident at administering your systems, and you know and trust the programs running on it, then you're probably going to be okay.

Using a firewall obviously overlaps with one feature of AppArmor, although you can still use it to ensure that apps don't misbehave by accessing/modifying local files in an unintended/malicious manner.

The performance impact of AppArmor shouldn't be much of a concern either, with the possible exception of I/O-bound tasks, according to [this older answer on the Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73519).

Comment: While this would make a thoughtful comment, I don't believe it actually answers my question. Why would I suspect apps which the distro installed, or the few apps I built from source and installed?

Comment: With the info you've provided, I don't think you can get a 'definitive' answer, although I welcome others to try. As with all security measures, it's a matter of identifying and balancing risk. Obviously, things bundled with the distro should be the safest, since those lists are maintained and checked by many people. Apps built from source could still contain bugs or backdoors unless you've scrutinized every line of code (and all the diffs with each update). Perhaps turn the question around, and ask yourself 'Is there any reason to uninstall AppArmor?'